# How to select multiple Row and multiple field by one code with SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to select multiple row on a table. But I want to select fields every row too. Here is sample table :

```
---------------------
OrNo | Name    | value 
---------------------
1154 | Michael | 41
1154 | Rico    | 24
1487 | Alex    | 21
1487 | Leo     | 27
```

I want to select based where "Orno" code which in the table is multiple. so I want to get every name and value on 1 of "OrNO".
For an example, I want to select where OrNO 1154. How to select all of name and value from that code? How to used sql data reader for read them?

Edit:

Based answered, I'm sorry, I want to execute on behind code, like sqldatareader with C#/VB.Net. I dont know how to execute them on behind code to store to varriable.

Thank you

Comment: Please don't throw irrelevant tags at your questions to get more views.  This question has nothing at all to do with C#, VB.NET or the `SqlDataReader` class.

Comment: IMO in database your intention is simple. Just go to [`w3school`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) to get the query

Comment: No no, I want to execute with sqldatareader on behind code. VB.NET or C#, I dont know how to execute with behind code

Comment: There are masses and masses of tutorials and examples on the web to show you how to use ADO.NET and a data reader specifically.  The only thing different about this case is the SQL required to get the desired data.  How you retrieve data with a data reader is exactly the same regardless of the SQL.  If you haven't actually bothered to read about how to use a data reader then you shouldn't be posting a question here yet.  The same applies if you have read but haven't tried to implement.  If you have tried to implement then show us what you've done and describe your SPECIFIC issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE OrNo IN
(
    SELECT OrNo
    FROM
    (
        SELECT OrNo, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount
        FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY OrNo
    ) A
    WHERE RecordCount > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your question.
Are you searching for the SQL Statement? If so, I would suggest:

```
SELECT *
FROM <TABLE_NAME> 
WHERE OrNo IN 
(
    SELECT OrNo
    FROM <TABLE_NAME>
    GROUP BY OrNo
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Sorry, @jmcilhinney was faster here.

Comment: I've never actually tried but can you confirm that you can definitely use an `IN` clause where the subquery produces multiple columns?  I should test for myself some time as I've always structured my queries to produce a single column in the subquery but things would be easier if that's not necessary.

Comment: That's an error in the query. Don't select `OrNo, COUNT(*) AS Count`, but only `OrNo` in the IN clause and you are fine.

Comment: Thank you Thorsten.
This should also be the answer for @jmcilhinney. The aspect in which my query differs from yours is (obviously) that I avoid a second subquery, which seems to be more simple and changeable. Especially if the query is more complicated, this variant will turn out less confusing. 
Of course your answer works fine, too :)

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Some DBMS, among them MySQL, Oracle and PostgreSQL, support `where (col1,col2) in (select colx,coly from ...)`. SQL Server doesn't unfortunately.

Comment: @Muli: jmcilhinney's query is unnecessarily complicated. Yours is syntactically wrong on the other hand as long as you select `count(*)`. As mentioned you don't have to select `count(*)`, but only use it in the `HAVING` clause. My solution in turn has the advantage that the table has to be read just once, so it's usually quicker and a tad more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You want to return duplicate records per OrNo, so count per OrNo and only return records with a count > 1.

```
select orno, name, value
from
(
  select orno, name, value, count(*) over (partition by orno) as cnt
  from mytable
)
where cnt > 1
order by orno;
```

Answer (score 0):

And one more, with ties

```
with t as (
  select * from (values 
    (1154,'Michael',41),
    (1154,'Rico',24),
    (1199,'Mary',25),
    (1487,'Alex',21),
    (1487,'Leo',27)) t(OrNo, Name, value )
)
select top(1) with ties OrNo, Name, value 
from t 
order by 
case count(*) over (partition by OrNo ) when 1 then 1 else 0 end
```